# VaultSharp AppRole Login Unwrapping problem

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vaultsharp

I logged in via the CLI using my standard Token obtained from the UI. Then I ran this to get a wrapping token:

```
vault write auth/approle/login role_id="e309ea24-994c-771e-939f-49e24a936ef2" secret_id="9597c7d0-3a88-c8f7-e43f-e8999600e38e"
```

that call returned:

```
Key                     Value
---                     -----
token                   s.5NuuJxEfdiJrfSiXXCU5MjZ6.dYgGw
token_accessor          3JFGpuaO45DuxD9nd6mUL6ic.dYgGw
token_duration          1h
token_renewable         true
token_policies          ["default" "transaction"]
identity_policies       []
policies                ["default" "transaction"]
token_meta_role_name    transaction
```

Now, I used the token in an unwrapping call like this:

```
IVaultClient vaultClientForUnwrapping = new VaultClient(
    new VaultClientSettings(_settings.Address, new TokenAuthMethodInfo(vaultToken: wrappingToken))
);

string appRoleAuthSecretId
    = vaultClientForUnwrapping.V1.System
        .UnwrapWrappedResponseDataAsync<Dictionary<string, object>>(tokenId: null)
            .Result.Data["secret_id"]
                .ToString();
```

And when attempting to run the Unwrapping call above, I get this exception:

**One or more errors occurred. ({"errors":["wrapping token is not valid or does not exist"]}**

Can anyone help out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `vault write auth/approle/login role_id="e309ea24-994c-771e-939f-49e24a936ef2" secret_id="9597c7d0-3a88-c8f7-e43f-e8999600e38e"` is **not** returning a [wrapped token](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/response-wrapping), but instead a raw token.

Essentially, in order to get a wrapped token, you need to provide the `-wrap-ttl` flag.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
vault server -dev -dev-root-token-id=root -dev-listen-address=127.0.0.1:8200 &
VAULT_SERVER_PID=$!
export VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
export VAULT_TOKEN=root

vault auth enable approle
vault write auth/approle/role/test-role policies=default
ROLE_ID=$(vault read -format=json auth/approle/role/test-role/role-id | jq -r .data.role_id)
SECRET_ID=$(vault write -f -format=json auth/approle/role/test-role/secret-id | jq -r .data.secret_id)
VAULT_WRAP_TOKEN=$(vault write -wrap-ttl=1h -format=json auth/approle/login role_id=${ROLE_ID} secret_id=${SECRET_ID} | jq -r .wrap_info.token)

VAULT_TOKEN=${VAULT_WRAP_TOKEN} vault write -f sys/wrapping/unwrap

kill -9 ${VAULT_SERVER_PID}
```

This is a sample script that would provide an actual *wrapped* token, and the process for unwrapping it. You can add the `-output-curl-string` flag to any of the `vault` commands above to see what the API commands might be. I've used `jq` for the programmatic passing of IDs to the next commands, but you can omit the `-format=json` and trailing  `| jq -r ...` if you wish to see the table-formatted responses from the `vault` binary.

The reason that most libraries that require Vault Tokens do the wrapping step is so that it can be certain that nothing except the end user of the token has ever seen the token. A wrapping token can only be used once, and so ensures that nothing else has unwrapped the token before being used.

However, in the case of VaultSharp, [a casual glance](https://github.com/rajanadar/VaultSharp/blob/master/README-0.6.x.md#app-role-authentication-backend) suggests that you can pass the Role ID and Secret ID directly to the library and have it generate its own tokens on demand. You may wish to look into this instead.

Comment: Every time I run with the token that is returned, even with the wrap-ttl flag, I get a "wrapping token is not valid or does not exist" error. Also, that version of AppRoleAuthenticationInfo, that uses the mountPoint, can be used but there is another version that uses only the role_id and secret_id, which I'm using. Using that only returns a "Client Token Missing" error

Comment: @MB34  Can you please let me know the json response you get with the wrap-ttl flag, and then your VaultSharp usage code? Also, let me know the Vault version and VaultSharp version being used. Feel free to create a GH issue on my project as well

Comment: The UI version we have is _1.3.2+prem_.
My local CLI is _v1.11.0 (ea296ccf58507b25051bc0597379c467046eb2f1), built 2022-06-17T15:48:44Z_. I'll post an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @RajaNadar, VaultSharp version is _1.7.0.4_, I posted the entire issue on GH...[https://github.com/rajanadar/VaultSharp/issues/276](https://github.com/rajanadar/VaultSharp/issues/276)

Comment: @spurgavie,    
I have tried using this via the CLI after logging in with my UI token. I have set my VAULT_ADDR and VAULT_NAMESPACE env variables to what we use.
_I am on Windows so cannot use jq_
`vault read -format=json auth/approle/role/trans/role-id
SET ROLE_ID=<returned role-id>

vault write -f -format=json auth/approle/role/trans/secret-id
SET SECRET_ID=<returned secret-id>

vault write -wrap-ttl=1h -format=json auth/approle/login role_id=%ROLE_ID% secret_id=%SECRET_ID%
SET VAULT_TOKEN=<returned wrap_info.token>

vault write -f sys/wrapping/unwrap`